# Match regex using array

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I made this in C++ and I wanted to convert to JavaScript:

```
foreach (QString pattern, extensions) {
    regex.setPattern(QString("\\.%1").arg(pattern));
    regex.setPatternOptions(QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);

    QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(filename);

    if (! match.hasMatch()) continue;

    return pattern;
}
```

It means that foreach `extensions` (that is an array of extensions) as `pattern` create a pattern with that to be like: `\\.png` (for example).
If there's a match it will return the found extension.

I tried to create exactly how I did in C++ but I don't know how to concatenate the returned string from the array to match

```js
const filename = 'example.wutt'
const extensions = ['wutt', 'xnss']

extensions.forEach(pattern => {
  const match = filename.match(`\\.${pattern}`)
  console.log(match)
})
```

It does work but it's not case-insensitive as I can't put the `i` flag.

How can I do that (and if there's a solution using ES6)?

Comment: you are missing a closing tick mark, and a closing parenthesis

Comment: I edited my question and I didn't noticed that I removed, but I put it back.

Comment: if you run the code, it says that `filename` isn't defined

Comment: Also your `c++` version returns a value in the loop, `forEach` in javascript won't break out of a forEach function if you return.

Comment: I didn't know that stackoverflow were this smart, I put the variable there as well

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, you are right, I think that JS has a few methods like `some`, `every`, etc, I don't know if any of those will help me with that but I will be testing.

Comment: you will want to do a `for(let i = 0;i<length;i++)` or `for(let item in extensions)` or Felix Kling's answer with the `find()`

Comment: Thank you, his answer was right (you helped a lot as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494035/218196) for building the regex.

If you want to find the extension that matches, you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const matchedExtension = extensions.find(
  ext => new RegExp(String.raw`\.${ext}$`, 'i').test(filename)
);
```

```js
var extensions = ['png', 'jpeg'];

var filename = 'foo.png';

console.log(extensions.find(
  ext => new RegExp(String.raw `\.${ext}$`, 'i').test(filename)
));
```

Couple of notes:

- [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings) is necessary to *not* treat `\.` as a string escape sequence but to pass it "as is" to the regular expression engine  (alternative you could escape the `\`, but `String.raw` is cool).
- `$` at the end of the pattern ensures that the pattern is only matched at the end of the file name.
- If you just want to know whether a pattern matches or not, [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is the preferred method.

If you are doing this a lot it makes sense to generate an array of regular expressions first (instead of creating the regex every time you call the function).

Comment: Why use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`?

Comment: From the question: *"If there's a match it will return the found extension."* `.filter` would work I guess, but there is probably only a single extension that matches.

Comment: You rock! Thank you all <3

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RegExp` constructor with `"i"` passed as second argument

```
extensions.forEach(pattern => {
    const match = filename.match(new RegExp(`\\.${pattern}$`, "i"));
    console.log(match);
})
```

Comment: Note that `.` matches any character. So If the filename was `opngate.gif`, it would match `.png`. You have to escape the `.` properly.

Comment: @FelixKling `opngate.gif` would not be matched using the pattern at Answer though you do have a point, see updated post.

Comment: Run ``"opngate.gif".match(new RegExp(`.png`, "i"))`` in your console ;)

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct. Ran test improperly. Was also missing `$` within `RegExp`. `[.]${pattern}` could alternatively be used.